# In-App-Purchase - confirmation alert shows after the product is bought

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've implemented IAP, I am testing it, but I have the following problem, for which I've searched a lot a solution. It does not happen all the time, which makes me blame the sandbox mode, but I don't think that is very smart, so I am asking for help:

1. tap buy product
2. shows alert to insert password for itunes
3. Did not insert password yet nor confirmed
   (Meanwhile in the back already product is bought, and it goes to the view showing the product.)
4. tap Cancel
5. It does not matter, already bought.

This is my code:

```
- (void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) 
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
            {
                NSLog(@"transaction state -> Purchasing");
                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
            {
                NSLog(@"purchased -- state");

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
                [self goToProductViewController];
                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
            {
                NSLog(@"transaction state -> RESTORED");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            }
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
            {
                NSLog(@"transaction state -> Cancelled");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }  
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the product bought before confirmation, before entering the password even? I am precisely calling the method for the bought product after has been purchased, not in the Purchasing state. If this is normal behaviour, then how can I catch the state where the product has been confirmed for buying? Only 4 times it acted normally, like it waited after the confirmation to actually call the method goToProductViewController, but the rest of dozens of tests it did not.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: does the confirmation appear after the purchase done? or does not appear at all? the user name and password alert

Comment: My goToProductViewController method is called before I confirm, or before I enter the username and password.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you aren't conforming to the **SKPaymentTransactionObserver** protocol.

If you haven't already, add `<SKPaymentTransactionObserver>` to your header file and implement the observer in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` (example below)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    /* ... */

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];
}
```

#### ~ Update Below

Since you setup the Observer, be sure that your app completes the transaction upon updating the entire UI and method calls to prepare for access of the new feature. Complete the transaction using:

```
SKPaymentTransaction *transaction = <# The current payment #>;
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
```

If this isn't called (or wasn't in the past) it could be causing the issue you're having currently.

Comment: Those are already done. In the header file I already have <SKPaymentTransactionObserver> and already adding the transaction Observer in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. My problem it's not that it does not work at all, I was asking why is the product purchased before I insert any password or before I even confirm the purchase?

Comment: I understand, you just hadn't clarified that you had and it could have been causing your previous transaction to be registered (like @hasan83 explained)

Comment: @CarmenA check my update. By calling this after completing all of the feature updates (or cancelation) your local transaction will be finalized.

Comment: I've seen your update, but as you can see in my code I am finishing transactions. I did not need to mention adding the first answer you gave me because in app purchase is functional, and if I haven't added what you mentioned it would not be. Your answers are basics for in app purchase functionality. I have a particular problem and that is the product is bought, before I confirm the purchase. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try to purchase another product with different Store Id. maybe your observer is catching the last purchase and not the one you just initialized. To check if that what is happenning try to test purchasing another product with different product id ofcourse. when your observer catches a purchase as bought. check the product id and compare it with the one you initialised just now.

note: you need to be focused doing this test cause if you missed that you need to re-test with new product id.

Comment: Done with several different product Id's. I have in my store somewhere around 50 different products. I almost never buy the same product again.

Comment: Wht happens when you only set an observer and dont go for a purchase?

Comment: Nothing... Should something happen?

Answer (score 0):

Four years late answer, but in case someone got in the same issue, if you are using a jailbroken device try to restart to the un-jailbroken system, I am not sure if there is a specific tweak which is causing this, but it worked.